# Porque el Controlador no lee la lista de Detalle de un archivo Json para Maestro Detalle?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

Estoy desarrollando un formulario maestro con detalles desde un JSON en el navegador hasta el servidor. La parte de Maestro del archivo json si se lee y se guarda en la base de datos pero el controlador no lee la parte de detalles (una lista) (en negrita la línea de código que no interpreta)( foreach (var x in reference.referenciascontenedores)) del archivo json pasado como parámetro reference.

Master Model:

```
  public partial class referencia
  {
     [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage    

    ("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public referencia()
    {
    referenciascontenedores = new HashSet<referenciascontenedore>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    ........

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage  
    ("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

    public virtual ICollection<referenciascontenedore> 
    referenciascontenedores { get; set; }

    }
```

Detail Model:

```
    public class referenciascontenedore
    {
       [Key]
       [Display(Name = "Contenedores Id")]
       public int ref_num { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("referencia")]        
     [Display(Name = "Referencia Id")]
      public int referenciaID { get; set; }

     .......
     [Required]
      public virtual referencia referencia { get; set; }
   }
```

View Model:

```
   public class referenciaViewModel
   {
        [StringLength(150)]
        [Display(Name = "Referencia")]
        public string ref_referencia { get; set; }
        ........

        public List<referenciascontenedore> referenciascontenedores { get; 
        set; } = 
        new List<referenciascontenedore>();       
   }
```

Controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public JsonResult Create(referenciaViewModel reference)
   {
      bool status = false;
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      referencia referencia = new referencia {ref_referencia =          
      reference.ref_referencia, ... };

      foreach (var x in reference.referenciascontenedores)**texto en   negrita**
   {
       referencia.referenciascontenedores.Add(x);
   }
   db.referencias.Add(referencia);                
   db.SaveChanges();
   status = true;
   }
   else
   {
        status = false;
   }
   return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
```

The Javascripfile:

```
    var referenciadetalle = 
    {
    ref_tipocontenedor: $('.select', this).val(),
    .....
    }
    list.push(referenciadetalle);

    if (isAllValid) {
    var data = {               
   ref_referencia: $('#ref_referencia').val(),
   ........,
   referenciascontenedores: list
   }

  data = JSON.stringify(data);
  alert(data);
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/Referencias/Create',
       //data: JSON.stringify(data),
       data : data,
       contentType: 'application/json',
       dataType: 'json',               
       success: function (data) {
           alert("Guardando");
           if (data.status) {
               alert('Guardados correctamente');
               //here we will clear the form
               list = [];
               $('#referenciadetallescontenedores').empty();
               window.location.href = "/Referencias/Index";
           }
           else {
               alert('Error');
           }
           $('#guardardetalles').val('Guardar referencia y  
            contenedores');
       },
       error: function (error) {
           console.log(error);
           $('#guardardetalles').val('Guardar referencia y 
           contenedores');
       }
     });
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Enterado. Gracias

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!